# Can two simultaneous DB transactions interfere with each other? ACID vs SELECT ... FOR UPDATE?

Tags: mariadb, transaction, php

This question may be considered as a follow-up question to [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270418/how-to-ensure-that-two-or-more-simultaneous-requests-to-a-mysql-table-dont-inte).

Imagine:

- a platform
- that provides a service X
- to book a service X, customer Y has to pay in advance
- every payment is authorized first only
- every payment is captured after the service has been received

From the booking of a service to the capture of the related payment, only the authorization is handled involving the client-side. All the rest is handled on the server-side.

For every possible case of a booking of a service on my platform, payment authorization is requested as the first action on the server-side. Adaptations of the DB of the platform are only executed after a successful authorization of the payment from the frontend.

The only fallback webhook I implement is for the case where a customer books a service, authenticates, and then loses connection. Because in this case, the customer would have booked the service, but the platform server could not make the related updates. So the customer will have paid, but not receive his / her service via the platform.

My strategy is thus to implement a webhook to listen for the event of a transaction authorization being "completed", and, if no transaction data is found internally, execute what needs to be done.

BUT, my concern is the following: The script which is triggered upon the incoming confirmation of a payment of a client must obviously cause the same changes as the one being triggered by the respective webhook. The content of that script can basically be summed up as (php):

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);

try{

// do all of your updates
mysqli_commit( $conn );

} catch (mysqli_exception $e ) {

mysqli_rollback( $conn );
mysqli_close( $conn );
// exit with error 

}

mysqli_close( $conn );
echo "all good!";
```

My concern is that the script of the webhook + the script triggered by the client-side request (after a payment is confirmed on the client-side) will be triggered at a very near moment. All I do at the start of my script is check if a given record X has a specific state like "completed", and if not, execute the script.

I'm however afraid that the webhook script is triggered first, checks the state, it's not "completed", so the script is triggered.
Then, while being in completion, the other non-webhook server-side script is triggered, checks the state, it's still not "completed", so that script is also triggered.

Or simply the other way around, as I cannot really control which of the two client-side scripts are executed first.

And yeah well, I'm really afraid that this will lead to issues that will corrupt my entire data. I also want to avoid that the entire DB transaction is run through twice for every payment, although the case of a lost connection at the precise moment after the payment authentication is very rare, to say the least. How can I assure that the exact same DB transactions do not interfere with concurrently (and identical) running DB transactions?

***UPDATE***

I'm somewhat confused, because the MariaDB docs tell you that DB transactions generally assure [Isolation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/acid-concurrency-control-with-transactions/), meaning that it is technically impossible that two transactions even concur with each other, or that one reads from a table while another is running a transaction on it.

On the other side, I see that people often mention [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/for-update/) as a solution, to explicitly lock rows from being accessed from other process until the commission of the executing transaction.

So I could do sth like this in my `try` block (error handling omitted for simplification):

```
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, 'SELECT payment_status FROM status_list WHERE ID = 10 FOR UPDATE');

if ( mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['payment_status'] === 'completed' ){
// do nothing
} else {
// execute updates ON OTHER ROWS & TABLES, and then
// DELETE FROM status_list WHERE ID = 10
}
```

The main goal would then be that two scripts holding the exact same content of the one above would, even if they're run at the same time, run one after the other. Precisely, the first query checking for the need of the execution of the rest of the code must only be executed after the transaction of the first script (whichever it may be, the server script or the webhook script) runs. To consequently maximally run the entire script + the first SELECT query only in every case, no matter if the webhook script or the regular script comes first.

Still, if the docs of MariaDB talk about the Isolation aspect of DB transactions, why is there such thing as `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`? I do not see the difference..?

***UPDATE 2***

Summary of Flow:

A) Client clicks on "book service" button

B) Payload with all service details is sent to platform server

C) Platform server inserts payload into new `status_list` table record

D) Platform server forwards back to frontend to confirm payment

E) If the authentication succeeds, this triggers:

E1) The REST call used to adapt the internal DB with the new reservation

E2) The webhook, because the event "payment authorized" has been triggered

So if the payment fails, E1 / E2 will never happen, and the reservation will never be booked. Only problem is that the record C) persists, but can easily be maintained with a cronjob + timestamps. The record should not be maintained for longer than sth like 30 seconds.

And if the payment succeeds:

- The server-side script checks if there is a record in `status_list` of a given ID
- IF YES:
- completes the entire DB transaction of the script
- deletes the record C)
- IF NOT:
- Does nothing

This logic should assure that E1 and E2 NEVER fully execute, only one
of them. And that none interferes with the other.

Is this the way to go? Also, still wondering about why we need `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` if we already have ACID....?

Comment: But do you "reserve" X before making the user pay for it?  If so, how do you "un-reserve" it if the payment fails?

Comment: Nope, that's my basic thought and why I think this is the best solution I can implement. Consider the `status_list` as a purely informative table, exclusively used to inform which payment authorizations have been LAUNCHED. And then, by the end of the transaction, if everything succeeded, delete that record from `status_list` to inform the second executed script that it will no longer need to be fully run. Makes sense?

Comment: So if the authorization fails, the record just stays there in the DB. But as neither the subsequent REST call is triggered (because failures are handled accordingly on the client-side) nor the webhook (as the payment was not authorized) nothing will get reserved. I could even implement an additional REST step upon failure to remove that record and / or cronjob for regular cleanup of the `status_list`. But the main focus is the webhook vs concurrent server confirmation of the payment. Do you have a better idea? O.O

Comment: The `status_list` in that sense just serves as tracker to let the server script vs webhook know if the tasks post - payment authorization have already been executed. And well the thing is that I need to provide a solution for the other big problem of losing the entire payload of the reservation if the thing will need to be solved via webhook API instead of a regular call. So I can combine the `status_list` to save the payload in the same record, and retrieve that via the PK upon confirmation / webhook, except if it's no longer there, meaning: already done. What do you think, makes sense?

Comment: @DevelJoe I answered a very similar question to yours on SO a few years ago, I suggest giving it a read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48629009/1797579  It may also answer your question on why transactions alone are not always sufficient.

Comment: If a database transaction takes more than a few seconds between `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`), a number of problems arise.  So, if your code (including going off to credit card validation service) might take longer than that, you should not use _just_ db transactions.

Comment: Nope it doesn't, the transaction usually completes in much less than a second. And even faster if I would execute the API calls to the payment service outside of it. May be wiser to take that part out of the transaction when using SELECT... FOR UPDATE, but seems like that's exactly what I'm looking for.. Do you see any drawbacks in using it in my case? @WillemRenzema cheers for the link to your excellent demo, I guess that what I've written under the first "UPDATE" block is thus validated?